Newton's approximation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$
Let $a > 0 $. We wish to approximate $1/\sqrt{a}$ with Newton's method for $a = 5, x_0 = 1$, with a relative error lesser than $10^{-4}$.
A naive approach would consist of proposing $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} - a$ defined only for $x > 0$. Clearly, the only root of $f$ is $r = 1 / \sqrt{a}$. However, observe that $f'(x) = \left( x^{-2} - a \right)' = -\frac{2}{x^3} $, which means
\begin{align*}
    x_{n+1} &= x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\ 
            &=x_n + ( 1 / x_n^2 - a ) \frac{x_n^3}{2} \\ 
            &=x_n + \left( x_n - ax^3_n \right) \frac{1}{2} \\ 
            &=\frac{3x_n - ax^3_n}{2}
\end{align*}
The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is alternating for $x_0 = 1, a = 5$, as can be proven via induction. The two base cases $x_0 = 1, x_1 = -1$, are skipped. If we assume for $2 \leq n \leq k$ that $x_n = x_{i \mod 2}$, we observe that
\begin{align*}
    x_{k+1} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( 3x_k - 5x_k^3 \right)  \\ 
            &= \frac{1}{2}\left( 3x_{k \mod 2} - 5x^3_{k \mod 2} \right) 
\end{align*}
If $k+1$ even, then $k$ is odd and $x_{k \mod 2} = x_{1} = -1$, so we have
\begin{equation*}
    x_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left( -3 + 5 \right)  = 1 = x_0
\end{equation*}
If $k + 1$ odd, it's similarly shown that $x_{k+1} = -1 = x_1$.
Thus, $\{x_n\} = \{1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots\}$. It follows that Newton's method does not converge to a solution with the chosen $f$.
How could $f$ be modified, or what other function $f'$ could be chosen, so that Newton's
approximation actually converges for $a = 5, x_0 = 1$?

Let $b=1/a=0.2$.  Then search for roots of $f(x)=x^2-0.2$

Why not rationalize the denominator and compute the square root of $5$? Then you can divide by $5$ to get the final answer.

Or why not start with $x_0 = \frac12$ instead of $x_0=1$?

You might also be interested in the fast inverse square root algorithm used in Quake which combines one step of Newton-Raphson with some clever computing tricks.

If you consider the equation $x^2- \frac 1a = 0$, the iteration reads $x_{n+1} = x_n-\dfrac{x_n^2-\frac 1a}{2x_n}= \dfrac{x_n}{2}+ \dfrac{1}{2a x_n}:=g(x_n)$. If $x_0 < 1/\sqrt{a}$ we have that $x_1 = g(x_0) > \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$, hence, we can just assume that $x_0 > \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and analyse the fixed point method convergence in the interval $I=[\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}, + \infty[$. Since $g$ is differentiable in $I$, $g(I)\subseteq I$ and $|g'|< 1$, the fixed point theorem establishes convergence to the unique fixed point.

I appreciate your answer. However, as indicated in its title, the question specifically verses on Netwon's method, so a solution using fixed-point iteration does not really address it.

@lafinur Newton's method is a particular fixed point iteration... The iteration I presented corresponds to newton's method applied to the equation $x^2-\frac 1a = 0$.

Thanks for clearing that up. I'm just a student and started studying these methods yesterday.

The iteration proposed by @FelixMarin has the advantage of converging for the given the initial guess, i.e., it answers the original question.
Here we consider the original iteration, i.e., the functional iteration
$$ x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$$
where
$$ g(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}, \quad f(x) = a - x^{-2}, \quad f'(x) = 2 x^{-3}.$$
As @lafinur has already observed we have
$$ g(x) = \frac{3x - ax^3}{2}.$$
We shall identify a region where the iteration converges monotonically, we shall discuss range reduction as well the advantage of this iteration over other methods. Finally, we shall consider how this iteration should be implemented on a binary computer and how to monitor the relative error.
Let $z= a^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ denote the reciprocal square root. We shall write the error $ g(x)-z$ as
$$ g(x)-z = C(x)(x-z),$$
where $C(x)$ can be determined by polynomial division as
$$ C(x) = \frac{1}{2} (2 - zax - ax^2).$$
It is clear that error will be reduced if and only if $$|C(x)| < 1.$$ It is straightforward to find the roots of $C$ and write
$$ C(x) = \frac{1}{2} (x + 2z)(x-z).$$
We see that
$$ g(x) - z = \frac{1}{2} (x + 2z) (x-z)^2.$$
This factorization explains the iteration will ultimately converge quadratically, because
$$ \frac{g(x) - z}{(x-z)^2} = \frac{1}{2}(x + 2z) \rightarrow \frac{3}{2}z, \quad x \rightarrow z, \quad x \not = z.$$
It is straightforward to verify that $|C(x)| < 1$ if and only if $$x \in I_z = (0, z \alpha), \quad \alpha = \frac{ \sqrt{17}-1}{2} z \approx 1.5616 z $$
We conclude that the iteration is quite resilient when it comes to choosing the initial guess. In particular, it will converge monotonically if the initial guess is less than 50% off.
This modest target can achieved with ease on a suitably reduced range of input. If $a > 0$, then there is a reduced argument $y \in [1,4)$ and integer $k$ such that
$$ a = y\cdot2^{2k}$$
It follows that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\cdot2^{-k}$$
Since $y \in [1,4)$ we have $1/\sqrt{y} \in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. It follows, that $$y_0 = \frac{3}{4}$$ is a good initial guess for all $y \in [1,4)$ and the associated relative error is strictly less than $\frac{1}{2}$. As an example we now return to the original case of $a=5$. Here the reduced argument is $y = 1.25$ and $k=2$. If the initial guess is $y_0 = 0.75$, then the sequence $y_{n+1} = g(y_n)$ has rapid monotone convergence as shown here where we obtain the floating point representation of the target value $1/\sqrt{y}$ in 5 iterations
  n      y_n-1/sqrt(y)
  0  -1.444271909999159e-01
  1  -3.309906599991586e-02
  2  -1.814626622429150e-03
  3  -5.518575919127855e-06
  4  -5.107392286873846e-11
  5                       0

It is important to appreciate the value of the original iteration, i.e.,
$$x_{n+1} = g(x_n) = \frac{3x_n - ax_n^3}{2}.$$
We observe that this iteration does not require any divisions on a binary computer because the division by $2$ can be accomplished using a binary shift. In particular, there is no need to compute the reciprocal value $1/a$ that is needed for some other iterations.
It is advantageous to implement the iteration as
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + x_n r_n, \quad r_n = \frac{1 - ax_n^2}{2}$$
Why is that?
This expression takes the form of a good approximation plus what will rapidly become a small correction. In particular, it is possible to compute the correction using reduced precision and still produce an accurate approximation of the target value. Moreover, the relative error is easily estimated, because
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} - x_n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}} =  \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} - x_n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + x_n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + x_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{a}-x_n^2}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + x_n\right)} \approx \frac{\frac{1}{a}-x_n^2}{2 \frac{1}{a}} = \frac{1 - ax_n^2}{2}$$
is a good approximation when $x_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}.$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{{1 \over \root{5}} = x} = {\Large ?}
\end{align}
$$
\mbox{It leads to}\ 5x^{2} - 1 = 0\quad\mbox{and}\quad 
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{x_{n + 1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{x_{n}} & \ds{-} & {\ds{5x_{n}^{2} - 1} \over \ds{10x_{n}}}
\\ \ds{x_{0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1}&& 
\end{array}\right.
$$
With a $\ds{\ \underline{little\ program}}$ you can see it is working in a perfect way:


In general, it is always better to choose a "good guess". For example
$$
5 = {1 \over x^{2}} \implies 4 < {1 \over x_{0}^{2}} < 9 \implies 
{1 \over 3} < x_{0} < {1 \over 2}
$$
and a "good guess" will be $\ds{x_{0} = {1/3 + 1/2 \over 2} = \color{red}{\large{5 \over 12}} \approx 0.4167}$ which is evidently a better choice than $\ds{1}$.
